# ASUS monitor turns off, replacing the power cord works for a while then it happens again

Tags: display, power, external-display

My ASUS monitor is turning off a couple of times a day and is unable to be turned back on. I discovered that replacing the power cord allows it to turn on again, and in fact if I just plug in another power cord for a few seconds and allow it to turn on, then unplug that and plug the original cord back in, it works again.

This has been going on for a couple of days.

The monitor is connected to my Macbook pro with a Mini Display Port to HDMI cable.

It seems like an interesting phenomenon, almost like needing a jump-start, does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: `Replacing the power cord`? Do you mean that the connection is 'killing' the chords, or do you have 2 power chords you're alternating?

Comment: "almost like needing a jump-start"  almost like curcuits inside for the power in the monitor are failing, and pulling the power causing a full reset, and a tiny cooldown gets it going.  Did you first try supercooling it (a fan or something) to see if the general monitor parts will run for longer if more cool?  It is possible before it breaks for good that it might be repaired by fixing the themal interfaces for the power curcuit stuff. All assuming there was no issue with software or the signal going to it.

Comment: @Dave I have 2 power cords. Alternating them gets it working.